# Bootstrap 3.0 Second level dropdown in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a customized bootstrap 3.36 menu. for desktop I changed onclick functionality to onhover. Now the problem is with mobile menu.

Below I have a short bit of my jquery code which I found and I have changed the code to meet my needs. However when I resize the window greater than 992px then I resize the window smaller than 992px the script stops running. I know I need an else statement to offset this behavior but I'm not sure what to put in the else statement. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  function checkWidth() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if (windowWidth <= 992) {
      $('ul.nav li > a.nav-dropdown').click(function () {
          $(this).parent().toggleClass("open");
          $(this).removeAttr("href");
      });
    }
    else {

    }
  }
  checkWidth();
  $(window).resize(checkWidth);

});
```

Comment: How about checking width after click dropdown instead of resizing !!!

Comment: That is an idea. Let me try that and see how its works.